# Multi Pane Mouse Events

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

We have a requirement to have a "main Node" that when the mouse hovers inside of it another Node ("hover popup Node") appears in the Scene. When the mouse hovers out of the "main Node" then the "hover popup Node" dissapears. Also, the "main Node" has an "inner Node" within that when clicked, another Node ("click popup Node") appears in the Scene and if clicked again the "click popup Node" dissapears.

The problem we have is that, when the mouse hovers inside the "inner Node", the "hover popup Node" dissapears which we do not want. We only want the "hover popup Node" to dissapear when the mouse hovers outside the "main Node". i.e. when the mouse is inside the "inner Node", we still want the "hover popup Node" to be visible.

See sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultiPaneMouseTest extends Application {

    private Rectangle hoverPopupNode;
    private Rectangle clickPopupNode;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        Rectangle mainNode = new Rectangle(200, 100);
        mainNode.setArcWidth(6);
        mainNode.setArcHeight(6);
        mainNode.setFill(Color.web("0x00ff00"));
        mainNode.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            System.out.println("mouse entered " + e);
            hoverPopupNode.setVisible(true);
        });
        mainNode.setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            System.out.println("mouse exited " + e);
            hoverPopupNode.setVisible(false);
        });

        Rectangle innerNode = new Rectangle(50, 25);
        innerNode.setArcWidth(6);
        innerNode.setArcHeight(6);
        innerNode.setFill(Color.web("0xffffff"));
        innerNode.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            System.out.println("mouse clicked " + e);
            clickPopupNode.setVisible(!clickPopupNode.isVisible());
        });

        hoverPopupNode = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        hoverPopupNode.setArcWidth(6);
        hoverPopupNode.setArcHeight(6);
        hoverPopupNode.setFill(Color.web("0x0000ff"));
        hoverPopupNode.setVisible(false);
        borderPane.setRight(hoverPopupNode);

        clickPopupNode = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        clickPopupNode.setArcWidth(6);
        clickPopupNode.setArcHeight(6);
        clickPopupNode.setFill(Color.web("0xff0000"));
        clickPopupNode.setVisible(false);
        borderPane.setLeft(clickPopupNode);


        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(mainNode);
        stackPane.getChildren().add(innerNode);
        borderPane.setCenter(stackPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setX(500.0);
        primaryStage.setY(500.0);
        primaryStage.setWidth(500.0);
        primaryStage.setHeight(500.0);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I've understood correctly, one solution, maybe not the best one, is to attach to the inner node a `onmouseentered` event: in this one you set, if not set, the property `visible` of the hoverpopupnode.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara, that would work well enough in this sample but not in our actual application. In our application as the inner Node has no direct access to the main Node's assoaciated hover popup Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `mainNode` a `Pane` (or suitable subclass) and add the `innerNode` to it as a child node. If there is a parent-child relationship between `mainNode` and `childNode`, then the mouse will still be considered to be hovering over `mainNode` when it is over `innerNode`. You can set the background of a `Pane` (or any region) to achieve the same fill and corner radius effects that you have on the `Rectangle`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultiPaneMouseTest extends Application {

    private Rectangle hoverPopupNode;
    private Rectangle clickPopupNode;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        StackPane mainNode = new StackPane();
        mainNode.setMinSize(200, 100);
        mainNode.setMaxSize(200, 100);

        mainNode.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.web("0x00ff00"), new CornerRadii(6), Insets.EMPTY)));

        // note you can replace these listeners with
        // hoverPopupNode.visibleProperty().bind(mainNode.hoverProperty());
        // (but obviously after the hoverPopupNode has been instantiated)

        mainNode.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            System.out.println("mouse entered " + e);
            hoverPopupNode.setVisible(true);
        });
        mainNode.setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            System.out.println("mouse exited " + e);
            hoverPopupNode.setVisible(false);
        });

        Rectangle innerNode = new Rectangle(50, 25);
        innerNode.setArcWidth(6);
        innerNode.setArcHeight(6);
        innerNode.setFill(Color.web("0xffffff"));
        innerNode.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            System.out.println("mouse clicked " + e);
            clickPopupNode.setVisible(!clickPopupNode.isVisible());
        });

        mainNode.getChildren().add(innerNode);

        hoverPopupNode = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        hoverPopupNode.setArcWidth(6);
        hoverPopupNode.setArcHeight(6);
        hoverPopupNode.setFill(Color.web("0x0000ff"));
        hoverPopupNode.setVisible(false);
        borderPane.setRight(hoverPopupNode);

        clickPopupNode = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        clickPopupNode.setArcWidth(6);
        clickPopupNode.setArcHeight(6);
        clickPopupNode.setFill(Color.web("0xff0000"));
        clickPopupNode.setVisible(false);
        borderPane.setLeft(clickPopupNode);


        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(mainNode);

        borderPane.setCenter(stackPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setX(500.0);
        primaryStage.setY(500.0);
        primaryStage.setWidth(500.0);
        primaryStage.setHeight(500.0);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```